# Using IP Webcam with OpenCV motion tracking

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, tracking

I'm trying to make a tracking laser webcam toy for my cat, but I am currently struggling with the IP webcam from an Android phone as it won't display anything and i get an error "initStream Failed to reset streams"  I have attached the code below! I'm still new to Python and would love to learn more! =)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#Cam
url = "http://192.168.x.x:8080/shot.jpg"
img_resp = requests.get(url)
img_arr = np.array(bytearray(img_resp.content),dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr,-1)
cap =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
#Movement tracker
while cap.isOpened():
    ret = cap.set(3,320)
    ret = cap.set(4,240)
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame, frame)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 900:
            continue
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 20, 30), 3)
        cv2.putText(frame, "Status: {}".format('Movement'), (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (200, 50, 180), 2)

        image = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720))
        cv2.imshow("feed", frame)
        ret, frame2 = img.read()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        img.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ***IP Webcam*** application on my android phone. Just need to define `url` variable as below:

```
url = 'http://your IP address:port number/video' # e.g. url = 'http://192.168.43.1:8080/video'
```

You will see ***IP address*** and ***port number*** on the mobile phone screen when the app is running.
And after that you need to pass `url` as an argument to `cv2.VideoCapture()` method like this `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)` instead of `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. It works fine for me. No need to say that PC and mobile phone are connected via Wi-Fi network (or mobile hotspot).